# URL different from view name ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, url-routing

Is it possible to add some sort of meta data to a view to make the URL to be different than the view name?

Example:

```
[DisplayName("My-View")]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
   return View();
}
```

As you see, I would like the url to be `www.mydomain.com/My-View` not `www.mydomain.com/MyView`.

I guess that can be sorted with some routing or IIS rewriting, but there really should be som sort of meta functionality to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ActionName` instead of `DisplayName`: [ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

This attribute will allow you to to start your action with a number or include any character that .net does not allow in an identifier. Via this way you can have nice URL's without the hassle of rewriting via other methods.

**Example**

```
[ActionName("My-View")]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Hey pjvds, I just tried this but cannot make it work, when I call the said action with an @Url.Action it complains that it can't find it no matter what Action Name I give it (be it My-View or MyView, to keep with the example)

Comment: @Nieszka See this post about the full `how a method becomes an action` process: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
[ActionName("My-View")]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    return View();
}
```